# Ehrenhest's theorem, momentum operator, commutation relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the following wikipedia section, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem#General_example

the following is stated

$$[p,p]=0 \rightarrow \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=0$$

Can someone expound on this for me?

Answer (score 2):

The cited article does not  say what you have written. It says that "since the operator $p$ commutes with itself *and* has no time dependence" (my emphasis) which is another thing entirely. Thus the time dependence of $\langle p \rangle$ comes entirely from the change in the wavefunction due to the potential $V$:
$$
\frac{\partial \langle p\rangle}{\partial t}=\frac 1{i\hbar}\langle [p,V]\rangle
$$ with no addional $\partial p/\partial t$.

Comment: ahhhhh! very important emphasis. can you explain why the momentum (or maybe the momentum operator?) does not depend on time? It seems odd that a canonical quantity like momentum or position would be static (in general).

Comment: You must be confusing the Schroedinger and Heisenberg Pictures. In the Schroedinger picture in position space $\hat p \to -i\hbar \partial_x$ has no time dependence ---- there is no "$t$" in $\partial_x$. All the time dependence resides in the wavefunctions $\psi(x,t)= \langle x|e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\psi\rangle$.  In the Heisenberg picture $\hat p(t) = e^{iHt/\hbar}\hat p(0) e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ is time dependent but the wavefunction  $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$ does not depend on $t$,

Comment: I see! So what you say implies:
$$
\frac{d \langle p\rangle}{d t}=\frac 1{i\hbar}\langle [p,V]\rangle
$$ 
is the Schrodinger picture, and 
$$
\frac{d \langle p\rangle}{d t} =\frac 1{i\hbar}\langle [p,V]\rangle +\frac{\partial \langle p\rangle}{\partial t}
$$ 
is the Heisenberg picture? Since $\frac{\partial \langle p\rangle}{\partial t}$ is non-zero in that POV?

Comment: No. The formula for $d<p>/dt$ is the same in both  cases. There is no $\partial o/\partial t$ because $\hat p$ only gets  its time dependence from the dynamics. It  has no explicit time depdence. You need to read a book on QM and understand the derivation.

Comment: How do you reconcile what you say which the Heisenberg equation of motion..? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture#Mathematical_details

or even see the Ehrenfest theorem wiki 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem